# Simulating a Google App Engine File Upload in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, file-upload

I have a Google App Engine app in Python that lets users upload files. After a file has been submitted, I get the file using

```
self.request.get('uploaded_file')
```

I get the filename using

```
self.request.POST['uploaded_file'].filename
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for it by manually creating a webapp request with the file set how I want it. However, I can't figure out how to initialize it such that I can get the uploaded file and its filename.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to test the blobstore functionality. when you generate a link to upload to it assumes that when it's done there's a server listening on a port to call a handler when it's done uploading. if you aren't running devappserver you won't get it.

Comment: The application doesn't use a blobstore or actually serve the files -- it just lets the user upload a file to validate it.  It's using a standard HTTP POST, which is put into a request object for the handler to respond to using the post() method that I implemented.

Comment: I was unaware that you could do that I would think that appengine would not allow form posts with files to route to your app because it would tie up an instance indefinitely. I guess that's not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're testing your handler, you're probably already creating a Webob request object and passing it to your handler, something like this:

```
request = webapp.Request({
    "wsgi.input": StringIO.StringIO(),
    "METHOD": "POST",
})
response = webapp.Response()
handler = MyHandler()
handler.initialize(request, response)
handler.post()
```

Uploaded files are `cgi.FieldStorage` objects, but `FieldStorage` is not particularly easy to test with. Instead, it's probably easiest to either use a mocking framework (such as mox) to create a mock, or just create a straightforward fake:

```
class FakeFieldStorage(object):
  def __init__(self, filename, value):
    self.filename = filename
    self.value = value
```

Then create one and add it to the request object before you pass it to the handler:

```
uploaded_file = FakeFieldStorage("test.txt", "foo")
request.POST['file'] = uploaded_file
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was doing, and I was having issues testing with `FieldStorage`.  I had to use `REQUEST_METHOD` instead of `METHOD` for it to realize that my request was a POST.  I also had to add `def __repr__(self): return self.value` to get the `FakeFieldStorage` to behave like a regular `FieldStorage` such that  `self.request.get('uploaded_file')` would work as expected, but this did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sam Bear in mind that `self.request.get('uploaded_file')` is just syntactic sugar for `str(self.request.POST['uploaded_file'])` in this case, and it's webapp specific. It's better - and usually easier - to just use the webob methods.

Answer (score 1):

Test it by having the test actually send a request with a file attached to your app, using `urlopen` or similar.

Then validate the response and the state after the upload.

Comment: To the downvoter: see http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down. I don't think my answer comes close to meeting those criteria; please post a comment explaining your problem if you think it does.

Comment: I might not be understanding your suggestion 100%.  It sounds like your suggesting starting up the server and actually sending a request to it.  I'm trying to test  that file uploads work correctly, and I want to do this in a unit test rather than a server test, meaning it should run quickly (without the overhead of actually starting up the app engine dev server so that it can respond to URLs) and should test just the function that responds to an uploaded file (without also testing that the other pages work correctly or not).

Comment: I'm reccomending you have your script actually send a file to the server, by opening it just like any web page, by it's url, with `urlopen`, with a file in the `POST` data, just like if a user were uploading to the site. Edit: You updated your comment. I don't think you can accurately test it without doing this.